# Using plotly to visualize infection spread

Tags: python, plotly, networkx, interactive

The following code is able to make network graph but the visual doesn't update when i use the slider to progress the infection. I'm looking for advice on how to make a visualization of how to show infection spread through a network.

I'm trying to make it so that the visualization has a slider on it too, so you can step through the spread and see where it expands the most.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import networkx as nx
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

def visualize_network(G, Nb_inf_init, HM, N, T):
    """
    Visualize the spread of an infection on a network graph using Plotly.

    Parameters:
        G (networkx.Graph): The network graph.
        Nb_inf_init (int): Initial number of infected nodes.
        HM (float): Infection probability.
        N (int): Total number of nodes in the graph.
        T (int): Number of time steps to simulate.

    """
    # Create initial infected nodes
    infected_nodes = set(random.sample(G.nodes(), Nb_inf_init))

    # Set initial node colors
    node_colors = ['red' if node in infected_nodes else 'blue' for node in G.nodes()]

    # Create initial network graph figure
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter(x=[], y=[], mode='lines', line=dict(color='gray', width=1)),
                         go.Scatter(x=[], y=[], mode='markers', marker=dict(color=node_colors, size=10))],
                    layout=go.Layout(showlegend=False, hovermode='closest'))

    # Set initial positions
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

    # Update figure with initial node positions
    for edge in G.edges():
        x0, y0 = pos[edge[0]]
        x1, y1 = pos[edge[1]]
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[x0, x1, None], y=[y0, y1, None], mode='lines', line=dict(color='gray', width=1)))

    for node in G.nodes():
        x, y = pos[node]
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[x], y=[y], mode='markers', marker=dict(color='red' if node in infected_nodes else 'blue', size=10)))

    # Initialize frames list
    frames = []

    # Create frames for each time step
    for t in range(T):
        # Update infected nodes and colors
        node_colors = ['red' if node in infected_nodes else 'blue' for node in G.nodes()]

        # Update figure with new node colors
        fig.data[1].marker.color = node_colors

        # Append the updated figure to the frames list
        frames.append(go.Frame(data=fig.data))

        # Spread the infection
        new_infected_nodes = set()
        for node in infected_nodes:
            for neighbor in G.neighbors(node):
                if neighbor not in infected_nodes and random.random() < HM:
                    new_infected_nodes.add(neighbor)

        # Update infected nodes
        infected_nodes.update(new_infected_nodes)

    # Add frames to the figure
    fig.frames = frames

    # Set up slider steps
    slider_steps = []
    for t in range(T):
        slider_steps.append({'args': [[t], {'frame': {'duration': 500, 'redraw': True}, 'mode': 'immediate'}],
                             'label': t, 'method': 'animate'})

    # Set up slider
    fig.update_layout(updatemenus=[{'buttons': [{'args': [None, {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'fromcurrent': True, 'transition': {'duration': 0}}],
                                                 'label': 'Play',
                                                 'method': 'animate'},
                                                {'args': [[None], {'frame': {'duration': 0, 'redraw': False}, 'mode': 'immediate'}],
                                                 'label': 'Pause',
                                                 'method': 'animate'}],
                                    'direction': 'left',
                                    'pad': {'r': 10, 't': 87},
                                    'showactive': False,
                                    'type': 'buttons',
                                    'x': 0.1,
                                    'xanchor': 'right',
                                    'y': 0,
                                    'yanchor': 'top'}],
                      sliders=[{'active': 0,
                                'currentvalue': {'font': {'size': 12}, 'prefix': 'Time: ', 'visible': True, 'xanchor': 'center'},
                                'transition': {'duration': 0},
                                'pad': {'b': 10, 't': 50},
                                'steps': slider_steps}])

    # Show the figure
    fig.show()
```

Here is an example of how i made a graph and then tried to run the visualization function on the graph

```
# Example usage
N = 500
k = 20
G1 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(N, k/N)
pos1 = nx.spring_layout(G1)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G1, pos1, alpha = 0.6, node_size=[2*i for i in list(dict(G1.degree).values())])
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G1, pos1, alpha=0.5)
plt.title("Erdos-Renyi")
plt.show()

# Set simulation parameters
Nb_inf_init = 10
HM = 0.1
N = len(G1.nodes)
T = 10

# Visualize the network graph and infection spread
visualize_network(G1, Nb_inf_init, HM, N, T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not suitable for animation, because you added to figure as many traces as the number of nodes and edges, and the slider steps are not connected to the frame. Each frame should contain only updates for node attributes (here the color) that varies in time.
To simplify, I defined one more function that derives   the lists of x and y coordinates for edges. These lists allow defining only two traces: one for edges and the second to nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random
def get_plotly_data(E, coords):
    # E is the list of tuples representing the graph edges
    # coords is the array of node coordinates, of shape (n,2) 
    Xedges = []
    Yedges = []
    for e in E:
        Xedges.extend([coords[e[0]][0], coords[e[1]][0], None])
        Yedges.extend([coords[e[0]][1], coords[e[1]][1], None])   
    return  Xedges, Yedges 

def frame_args(duration=400, redraw=False): 
    #function to set frame attributes
    #redraw must be set on True for any other trace type different from scatter
    return dict(
         frame_duration= duration,
         mode= "immediate",
         fromcurrent=True,
         redraw=redraw, 
         transition=dict(duration= duration, easing="linear")
        )
def visualize_network(G, Nb_inf_init, HM, N, T):
    """
    Visualize the spread of an infection on a network graph using Plotly.

    Parameters:
        G (networkx.Graph): The network graph.
        Nb_inf_init (int): Initial number of infected nodes.
        HM (float): Infection probability.
        N (int): Total number of nodes in the graph.
        T (int): Number of time steps to simulate.
    """
    # Create initial infected nodes
    infected_nodes = set(random.sample(G.nodes(), Nb_inf_init))
    # Set initial node colors
    node_colors = ['red' if node in infected_nodes else 'blue' for node in 
       G.nodes()]
    # Set initial positions
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    coords=np.array([pos[node] for node in G.nodes])
    Xe, Ye = get_plotly_data(G.edges, coords)
    Xn, Yn = coords.T
    markercolor=['red' if node in infected_nodes else 'blue' for node in G.nodes]
    fig=go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=Xe, y=Ye, mode='lines', line=dict(color='gray', 
                             width=1)),
                   go.Scatter(x=Xn, y=Yn, mode='markers', 
                             marker=dict(color=markercolor, size=10))])
    frames = []
    for t in range(T):
        # Update infected nodes and colors
        node_colors = ['red' if node in infected_nodes else 'blue' for node in G.nodes()]
        frames.append(go.Frame(data=[go.Scatter(marker_color=node_colors)],
                               traces=[1], #1 is the index of fig.data that is updated
                               name=f"fr{t}"))

        # Spread the infection
        new_infected_nodes = set()
        for node in infected_nodes:
            for neighbor in G.neighbors(node):
                if neighbor not in infected_nodes and random.random() < HM:
                    new_infected_nodes.add(neighbor)

        # Update infected nodes
        infected_nodes.update(new_infected_nodes)

    # Add frames to the figure
    fig.frames = frames
    fig.update_layout(width=700, height=600, showlegend=False,
        sliders =[dict(active=0, 
                         len= 0.9,
                         pad= dict(b= 10, t= 60),
                         x= 0.1, y=0, #slider starting position
                         xanchor= "left",
                         yanchor= "top",
                         steps=[dict(label=f"fr{k}",
                                     method="animate",
                                     args=[[f"fr{k}"], # match the frame[:name]
                                           frame_args()
                                 ]) for k in range(T) ]
             )],
           updatemenus=[
            dict(type= "buttons",
                 buttons= [
                    dict(
                        args= [None, frame_args()],
                        label= "&#9654;",
                        method= "animate",
                    ),
                    dict(
                        args= [[None], frame_args(duration=0)],
                        label= "&#9724;",
                        method= "animate",
                    )
                ],
                pad = dict(r=10, t=70),
                direction= "left",
                x=0.1, y=0, #button position 
                xanchor= "right",
                yanchor= "top"
            )
        ])
    fig.show()
N = 200
k = 20
G1 = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(N, k/N)
pos1 = nx.spring_layout(G1)

Nb_inf_init = 10
HM = 0.1
N = len(G1.nodes)
T = 10
visualize_network(G1, Nb_inf_init, HM, N, T)
```